# MQTT subscription

Tags: mqtt, subscription, payload

Can someone help me with this code?

The goal is to trigger a Led when the value of the payload is > 1000.

It is a MQTT subscribtion code based on the esp8266mqtt PubSub client example. I will use it for a subscribyion of a topic from a CO2sensor

I've tried to modify a part of it but I think it has yo do something with the kind of datatype or a wrong condition?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.

const char *ssid = "xxx";
const char *password = "xxx";
const char *mqtt_server = "xxxx";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
long lastMsg = 0;
char msg[50];
int value = 0;
int led = D4;

void setup_wifi()
{

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if value of C02 is above 1000
  i = atoi (payload); //convert string to integer
  if ( i > 1000)      // comparison
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // Turn the LED on 
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW); // Turn the LED off 
  }
}

void reconnect()
{
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected())
  {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str()))
    {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      //client.publish("outTopic", "Test");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("my/sensors/co2");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop()
{
  if (!client.connected())
  {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
}
```

Kind regards

Hi, This is what I publish:

```html
void pubMessage() {
      char message[16];    
      snprintf(message, sizeof(message), "%d", co2);
      client.publish("my/sensors/co2", message);
      delay(30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are casting the first byte of `payload` to a char.

Since it's just the first byte, it has a max value of 256.

Second you are comparing that 1 bytes value to the string `'1000'`

Without knowing exactly what you are publishing it is very hard to tell you how to fix it.

If you are publishing a string representing the number then you will need to parse it first with `atoi()` then do the comparison to the integer `1000` not the string.

If it is a byte value then you will need to read the correct value from the incoming byte array before doing the comparison.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58882576/edit) the question to add more detail.

Comment: I have added my publish code and this is a byte value?

Comment: No this is a string value

Comment: Ok I did the conversion and comparison but I get a compile error: `error: invalid conversion from 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: That is a totally separate problem, ask a new question